# Maximum number of concurrent kernels & virtual code architecture

Tags: cuda, compute-capability

So I found this [wikipedia resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications)

> Maximum number of resident grids per device
>   (Concurrent Kernel Execution)

and for each compute capability it says a number of concurrent kernels, which I assume to be the maximum number of concurrent kernels.

Now I am getting a GTX 1060 delivered which according to [this nvidia CUDA resource](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) has a compute capability of 6.1. From what I have learned about CUDA so far you can specify the virtual compute capability of your code at compile time in NVCC though with the flag `-arch=compute_XX`.

So will my GPU be hardware constrained to 32 concurrent kernels or is it capable of 128 with the `-arch=compute_60` flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to table 13 in the [NVIDIA CUDA programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) compute capability 6.1 devices have a maximum of 32 resident grids = 32 concurrent kernels.

Even if you use the `-arch=compute_60` flag, you will be limited to the hardware limit of 32 concurrent kernels.  Choosing particular architectures to compile for does not allow you to exceed the hardware limits of the machine.

Comment: On a side note, 32 concurrent kernels are plenty and it is essentially impossible to ever hit this limit. As the GTX 1060 has either 9 or 10 SMs, even in the extreme case where you launch a long series of single block kernels where 3 fit onto an SM you still only reach 30 concurrent kernels.

Comment: @tera, does the maximum concurrent kernel limit apply the same when using dynamic parallelism and nested kernels?

Comment: @tera I'm wondering why only 3 kernels can fit onto 1 SM. Are there any documents for this?

Comment: 3 blocks per SM is not a hard limit, but a typical value. Use the [occupancy calculator spreadsheet](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-occupancy-calculator/index.html) or the [occupancy calculator API](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-occupancy-api-simplifies-launch-configuration/) to find out how many blocks of a given kernel can fit onto one SM at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the accepted answer, it is now **Table 15** in the [NVIDIA CUDA C Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) as of April 2022, with the latest CUDA version being 12.1. Or, you can just search **Technical Specifications per Compute Capability** in the docs.